# Adding multiple nodes / anchors in the SCNSceneRenderer nodeFor

Tags: ios, xcode, arkit, aranchor

I'm struggling to understand how to add multiple anchors into a scene.

I have an imageAnchor which works fine, it recognises the image and puts a video on top.

Now I want to add a sphere node anchored to the floor in the scene somewhere else separately that always stays in position and I can move the camera around it. (ideally I would like the floor tracked and the user can put the sphere somewhere).

The trouble is adding it as a childnode just anchors it to the existing image node.

But making a new node means it doesn't appear at all?

Brief code example:

```
 func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, nodeFor anchor: ARAnchor) -> SCNNode? {
        
        let node = SCNNode()

      if let imageAnchor = anchor as? ARImageAnchor {
... code here for the image anchor reference images etc...

let plane = SCNPlane(width: imageAnchor.referenceImage.physicalSize.width, height: imageAnchor.referenceImage.physicalSize.height)

            plane.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = videoScene
            let planeNode = SCNNode(geometry: plane)
            plane.firstMaterial?.isDoubleSided = true
            planeNode.eulerAngles.x = .pi / 2
            
            planeNode.name = imageAnchor.name
            
            node.addChildNode(planeNode)
            
            
            return node

}

      
      // ADDING NEW SPHERE NODE WITH LOOPING VIDEO
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            var sphereNode = SCNNode()
            
        
            let newscene = SCNScene(named: "art.scnassets/SphereSpace.usdz")
            sphereNode = (newscene?.rootNode.childNode(withName: "Space", recursively: true)!)!
            sphereNode.scale = SCNVector3(x:0.15, y:0.15, z:0.15)
            sphereNode.name = "Space"
            sphereNode.position = SCNVector3(x:0.10, y:0.00, z:-0.1)
   
            let sphereplayer: AVPlayer
            let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: self.videoName, withExtension: self.videoType)
            let item = AVPlayerItem(url: url!)
            sphereplayer = AVPlayer(playerItem: item)

            sphereNode.geometry?.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = sphereplayer
            sphereplayer.play()
            
            NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: .AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime, object: sphereplayer.currentItem, queue: nil) { (notification) in
                
        sphereplayer.seek(to: CMTime.zero)
       sphereplayer.play()
                             

      print("New Looping Video")
                        }
              
                       }
        // THIS JUST ADDS THE SPHERE TO THE EXISTING NODE. 
//IF I TRY SETTING UP A SECOND NODE (Node2) IT DOES NOT APPEAR IN THE SCENE

            node.addChildNode(sphereNode)
     
        }
```

What am I doing wrong? I can't understand how to add it separately?

Thanks

[Explanation of current behaviour / expected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cKfkY.jpg)